# uWSGI workers all busy, yet requests per second is very low

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm having quite a bit of trouble optimizing `uWSGI` to serve my `Flask` application, which receives around 1500 requests per second.

I currently am running Nginx on my front-facing server with four servers (each an AWS m5-xlarge, so there's plenty of computing power) in an upstream block. The front-facing server connects to the uWSGI servers on port 5000 using web sockets. I have verified that this is all working and that Nginx is capable of handling the load.

Here is my uWSGI configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true

processes = 24
threads = 4
enable-threads = True

socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
stats = api.stats.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

Here is a screenshot of the typical `uwsgitop` stats for each server:

[image: uWSGI Stats]

As you can see, the requests per second is extremely low yet the workers are still busy.

The `top` command shows that my server utilization is *extremely* low.

[image: top]

Meanwhile, Nginx is spitting out thousands of errors such as:

```
*5151324 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream
```

If anyone can help me diagnose this, that would be super appreciated.

Comment: have you considered that you may have deadlock(s) here hence the timeouts? https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/1149

Comment: Not quite sure if it would be deadlocks. After proxy_pass'ing to an nginx instance on uWSGI servers, it looks like there were too many connections to the socket (subsequent requests failed with socket error 11). It seems like the requests would just hold on to the socket until they timed out, despite a response already being sent. I ended up transferring everything over to use Apache's WSGI module with the worker mpm and everything is super performant now. Would still be curious as to why this issue was occurring though.

Comment: @AaronWojnowski I must say it is expected behavior: uwsgi workers execute your python code (your app). Nothing in your question indicates that your app is pure maths exercise - I would expect it was blocking on some restapi or blockio. So what's there you are asking about exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where my listen queue was growing and the RPS was low despite all the workers idling.

There are a lot of potential causes

- net.ipv4.ip_conntrack_max not high enough
- net.core.somaxconn not high enough
- ulimit not high enough
- uwsgi --listen not high enough
- nginx worker processes too low
- nginx worker connections too low

If none of these work, then you'll want to check your logs that inbound requests to uWSGI are under http/1.1 and not http/1.0, and then use `--http11-socket`

Here are some of my findings when I wrestled with this issue: https://wontonst.blogspot.com/2019/06/squishing-performance-bug-in.html

Answer (score -1):

uWSGI all worker **busy**, possible the queue is blocking. Check database or other operation which cost too much time.

I had similar issue like you, and solved is Postgresql 12 problem, the connections up to limit. Default max_connections is 100. I changed this config to 10000.

```
alter system set max_connections='10000';
```

and restart db

```
systemctl restart postgresql-12
```

That's solved, maybe it's a reference, maybe not similar reason, I hope it's helpful.